# Sorting nested While() Loops

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop, nested

I'm able to sort the second tier while loop for obvious reasons but I cannot get the first one to sort. I know its cause the "for" loop is incrementing. What I want is alphabetically sort first while loop then the second ASC...any suggestions? Here's my code

```
function get_content() {
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM category";
    $res1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
    $total = mysql_num_rows($res1) or die(mysql_error());

    for($a = 1; $a <= $total; $a++) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM weblinks INNER JOIN category ON category_weblinks = id_category WHERE id_category = '$a' AND status_weblinks = 'checked' ORDER BY title_weblinks ASC";
        $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            echo "\n\n\n" . '<div class="post">' . "\n";
            echo '<div class="title">' . "\n";
            echo '<h2><a name="' . $row['shortcut_category'] . '">' . $row['title_category'] . '</a></h2>' . "\n";
            echo '<p><small>Posted by Joe <a href="mailto:"> email</a></small></p>';
            echo '</div>' . "\n";
            echo '<div class="entry">' . "\n";
            $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                echo "\n" . '<p><b>' .$row['title_weblinks']. '</b><br>' . "\n";
                echo $row['description_weblinks']. '<br>' . "\n";
                echo 'Link: <a href="' .$row['link_weblinks']. '" target="_blank">' .$row['link_weblinks']. '</a><br>' . "\n";
                echo 'User: ' .$row['username_weblinks']. ' | Password: ' .$row['password_weblinks']. '</p>' . "\n";
            }
            echo '<p class="links"> <a href="#" class="more">Back to Top</a></p>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you re-executing the same query again inside your loop? First, it doesn't look like it buys you anything, and two, your re-use of variables is going to mess up your outer loop.

Comment: obligatory comment regarding outdated  use of deprecated `mysql_`

Comment: My goal was to create categories and links within the categories. Rather than put a static category I was hoping loop them from my database and also loop the links assigned to the category in a loop as well. I got it to work but since I did a "for" to increment the category id I can't sort from it. Should I just scrap the whole thing since I'm not using mysqli?

Comment: @JoePerez 1) You should be able to do what you want using only one query to your database since you don't add or change any variables in your outer `while` loop, that is, unless you're missing something. 2) Use of `mysql_` has no bearing on whether this should work, it's recommended that you update your code to use `mysqli_` anyway.

Comment: Thank you, I tried using one while loop and I got so many duplicate rows cause the second loop didn't have a condition to tie it to the parent category. I'm not sure how to tie the rows from my links table to the parent category. I'm a novice so this is troubling :-/